# Problem with RabbitMQ Direct reply-to with Spring

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm working on an apllication that sends message to as server, then given message is modified and sent back to the `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` queue using Direct Reply-to . I've followed the the tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html but I have some problems to implement it. In my case as I've understood I need to consume message from pseudo-queue `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` in no-ack mode, Which in my case is `MessageListenerContainer`. Here's my config:

```
@Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter() {    
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(mapper);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to");
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory ) {       
        DirectMessageListenerContainer directMessageListenerContainer = new DirectMessageListenerContainer();
        directMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        directMessageListenerContainer.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
        directMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to");
        directMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(new PracticalMessageListener());
        return directMessageListenerContainer;

    }
```

Message is sent as JSON through the SEND frame on STOM protocol and converted. Then a new queue
is created dynamically and added to the MessageListenerContainer. So when the message arrives in the broker, I would like to modify it on the server side and send back to `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` and original message to be sent to routing key `messageTemp.getTo()` which is subscribed on the SUBSCRIBE frame in STOMP.

```
  @MessageMapping("/private")
  public void send2(MessageTemplate messageTemp) throws Exception {
      MessageTemplate privateMessage = new MessageTemplate(messageTemp.getPerson(),
              messageTemp.getMessage(), 
              messageTemp.getTo());

     AbstractMessageListenerContainer abstractMessageListenerContainer =
              (AbstractMessageListenerContainer) mlc;

       // here's the queue added to listener container   
      abstractMessageListenerContainer.addQueueNames(messageTemp.getTo());

      MessageProperties mp = new MessageProperties();
      mp.setReplyTo("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to");
      mp.setCorrelationId("someId");

      Jackson2JsonMessageConverter smc = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
      Message message = smc.toMessage(messageTemp, mp);


      rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive( 
              messageTemp.getTo() , message);
  }
```

Message is modified onMessage method when message sent to `messageTemp.getTo()` routing key

```
@Component
public class PracticalMessageListener implements MessageListener {

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(("message listener.."));
        String body = "{ \"processing\": \"123456789\"}";
       MessageProperties properties = new MessageProperties();

       // some business logic on the message body

        properties.setCorrelationId(message.getMessageProperties().getCorrelationId());
        Message responseMessage = new Message(body.getBytes(), properties);

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("", 
                message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), responseMessage);
    }
```

I may misunderstand the concept of direct-reply and the documentation that says:

> Consume from the pseudo-queue amq.rabbitmq.reply-to in no-ack mode. There is no need to declare this "queue" first, although the client can do so if it wants.

The question is where I need to consume from that queue? And how Can I access that modified message if I'm getting error:

```
2020-01-15 22:17:09.688  WARN 96222 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.patrykmaryn.spring.second.PracticalMessageListener.onMessage(PracticalMessageListener.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
```

Which is coming from the place when I invoke `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` in `PracticalMessageListener`

**EDIT**

I got rid of setting `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` in the `DirectMessageListenerContainer` and implemented `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer`:

```
@Bean
    DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc =
                new DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        drtmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        drtmlc.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
        drtmlc.setMessageListener(new DirectMessageListener());
        return drtmlc;
    }
```

The problem must be in `onMessage` method that doesn't allow to invoke any send method on `rabbitTemplate`, I've tried with different existing routing keys and exchanges. The listening is coming from queue defined with routing key `messageTemp.getTo()`.

```
@Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println(("message listener.."));

        String receivedRoutingKey = message.getMessageProperties()
           .getReceivedRoutingKey();
        System.out.println(" This is received routingkey: " + 
            receivedRoutingKey);

           /// ..... rest of code goes here

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("", 
                message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), 
                responseMessage);
```

Where `messageTemp.getTo()` is routing key defined at runtime, by selecting a receiver e.g if i select 'user1' it will print out 'user1'.

That's the first attempt to send message:

```
2020-01-16 02:22:20.213 DEBUG 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Searching methods to handle SEND /app/private session=45yca5sy, lookupDestination='/private'
2020-01-16 02:22:20.214 DEBUG 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Invoking PracticalTipSender#send2[1 args]
2020-01-16 02:22:20.239  INFO 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : SimpleConsumer [queue=user1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-Evyiweew4C-K1mXmy2XqUQ identity=57b19488] started
2020-01-16 02:22:20.268  INFO 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-01-16 02:22:20.269  INFO 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] .l.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer : Container initialized for queues: [amq.rabbitmq.reply-to]
2020-01-16 02:22:20.286  INFO 28490 --- [nboundChannel-6] .l.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer : SimpleConsumer [queue=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to, consumerTag=amq.ctag-IXWf-zEyI34xzQSSfbijzg identity=4bedbba5] started
```

And second that fails:

```
2020-01-16 02:23:20.247 DEBUG 28490 --- [nboundChannel-3] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Searching methods to handle SEND /app/private session=45yca5sy, lookupDestination='/private'
2020-01-16 02:23:20.248 DEBUG 28490 --- [nboundChannel-3] .WebSocketAnnotationMethodMessageHandler : Invoking PracticalTipSender#send2[1 args]
2020-01-16 02:23:20.248  WARN 28490 --- [nboundChannel-3] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Queue user1 is already configured for this container: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer@3b152928, ignoring add
2020-01-16 02:23:20.250  WARN 28490 --- [nboundChannel-3] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Queue user1 is already configured for this container: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer@3b152928, ignoring add
message listener..
 This is received routingkey: user1
2020-01-16 02:23:20.271  WARN 28490 --- [pool-1-thread-5] s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler : Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
```

**EDIT**

Putting `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` in a separate class and setting its `MessageListener` as a `@Bean` and also 
`directMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(practicalMessageListener());` as `@Bean` seemed to get rid of NPE. But still even the reply goes to  `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABVyYWJ.....` it doesn't seem to be listened in the `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc`.

```
@Component
class DirectMessageListener implements MessageListener {
    // This doesn't get invoked...
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("direct reply message sent..");

    }
}

@Component
class ReplyListener {

    @Bean
    public DirectMessageListener directMessageListener() {
        return new DirectMessageListener(); 
    }

    @Bean
    DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc (ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc =
                new DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        drtmlc.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        drtmlc.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
        drtmlc.setMessageListener(directMessageListener());
        return drtmlc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have mis-understood the feature.

Each channel gets its own pseudo queue; you can only receive from that same channel so a general message listener container won't hack it.

> `directMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to");`

You simply can't do that.

The framework already supports direct reply-to directly, internally in the `RabbitTemplate`. The `RabbitTemplate` has its own `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` which maintains a pool of channels.

Each request checks out a channel and the reply is returned there and then the channel is returned to the pool for reuse by another request.

Use `RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()`; the default behavior (in recent versions) will automatically use direct reply-to.

**EDIT**

Why not let the framework do all the heavy lifting and you just concentrate on your business logic:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So59760805Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So59760805Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(cf);
        container.setQueueNames("foo");
        container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new MyListener()));
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyExtendedTemplate template(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return new MyExtendedTemplate(cf);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> System.out.println(template.convertSendAndReceive("", "foo", "test"));
    }

}

class MyListener {

    public String handleMessage(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

}

class MyExtendedTemplate extends RabbitTemplate {

    MyExtendedTemplate(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        super(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Response received (before conversion): " + message);
        super.onMessage(message);
    }

}
```

The rabbit template uses direct reply-to (internally) by default.

```
Response received (before conversion): (Body:'TEST' MessageProperties [headers={}, correlationId=1, ...receivedRoutingKey=amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkAA5yYWJiaXRAZ29sbHVtMgAAeE0AAADmAw==.RQ/uxjR79PX/hZF+7iAdWw==, ...
TEST
```

Comment: Does it mean I need to implement `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` and `.setQueueNames("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")`.? Or if it supports direct reply-to setting queue `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` is not needed?. Problem is bc sending to the queue `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` gets invoked when message arrives on queue with routing key `getReplyTo()`, listening by `directMessageListenerContainer`. Even after using `RabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive()` I still get the same NPE.

Comment: No; the `rabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive(..)` (or `convertSendAndReceive()`) takes care of everything, including setting up the replyTo and correlation id. It appears your `PracticalMessageListener` is attempting to consume from `"amq.rabbitmq.reply-to"` which is just wrong; it should be consuming from whatever `messageTemp.getTo()` is set to and reply to the `replyTo()` - if you examine that in a debugger, you will see it is a unique pseudo queue name.

Comment: I don't know why invoking `rabbitTemplate` send method inside `onMessage `method makes NPE. `PracticalMessageListener` consumes `messageTemp.getTo() `that I checked printing `message.getMessageProperties().getReceivedRoutingKey()`.

Comment: `drtmlc.setMessageListener(new DirectMessageListener());` - that means Spring is not managing that bean so if you are auto wiring the template, it won't work - it needs to be a `@Bean` or you need to pass in the template yourself. However, one more time, you should NOT be using a `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer` there - that is used by the template on the client side (send/receive) to receive the reply. The server side just needs a regular listener container (simple or direct).

Comment: I registered `drtmlc.setMessageListener(directMessageListener())` where `directMessageListener()` is a `@Bean` in a separate class. But still doesn't listen a message sent do `message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo()` in the `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` in `onMessage` method

Comment: I've tried to get rid of implementation `DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer drtmlc` and extend class RabbitTemplate and  implement `onMessage` method but still doesn't listen any message.. `@Component           
class ReplyTemplate extends RabbitTemplate {
 
 @Override
 public void onMessage(Message message) {
  System.out.println("direct Message sent..");
  
 }`

Comment: You are over-complicating things, you don't have to get involved with all this low-level stuff; leave it to the framework and concentrate on your business logic - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I'd like to convertSendAndReceive to `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` and how can i access message sent to it? In other words how can I consume messages going to that pseudo-queue?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. You simply cannot do that; there is no such queue to send to; as discussed in the documentation you can only consume from that pseudo queue on the channel that sent the message; messages sent from this channel that set the `replyTo` to that value are received with a unique pseudo queue (`amqp.rabbitmq.reply-to+UUID`) that is mapped within the broker to the sending channel's direct reply-to channel.

Comment: That's what I understand. I'm sendind a message to `messageTemp.getTo()` with properties `setReplyTo("amq.rabbitmq.reply-to")`. When this message is consumed `onMessage` it takes the property `replyTo` and sends modified message to let's say `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to.g2dkABff452...`. At this moment how can I consume this modified message or how can I access it?

Comment: Please read my answers carefully; you simply can't do it; you can only consume such messages on a consumer that is created **on the channel that sent the original request message**. The `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()` does all of that internally; there is no need to write your own code to do that. If you really want to do it, for some reason, you need to use the amqp-client directly or use `RabbitTemplate.execute()` and use the low-level APIs, which removes most of the benefit of using Spring.

Comment: Consumer is created on the channel `replyTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("",messageTemp.getTo() , message)` where `replyTemplate` is extended `rabbitTemplate`, with own `onMessage` method. That method consumes the message received from Server side which is `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("", 
                message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), 
                responseMessage)` However when I do `Object mObject = replyTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("", 
     messageTemp.getTo() , message);` I get null.

Comment: But WHY are you extending the standard template when it deals with all this stuff itself? My example above has everything you need. Exactly WHAT are you trying to achieve that the framework doesn't already do for you?

Comment: I'd like to access the response message received from `rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("", message.getMessageProperties().getReplyTo(), responseMessage)`. Either by `onMessage` call or assigning `Object mObject = replyTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("", messageTemp.getTo() , message)`, but I can't get `mObject`

Comment: I wish you'd said that up front; none of this has anything to do with direct reply-to. I updated my example to show how to access the raw reply message before it is converted to the reply result.

Comment: Thanks Gary for help. One more question. The message you get in your solution `MyExtendedTemplate`, is there any way to get that message not being consumed by 'onMessage' and being assign directly as mentioned `Object mObject = replyTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("", messageTemp.getTo() , message)`?

Comment: Not with `convertSendAndReceive()` (out of the box) because conversion is two-way. If you want the raw message as the reply, either use `sendAndReceive` (sending a `Message`) or use a custom `MessageConverter` that performs no conversion in `fromMessage()`. You can subclass one of the standard converters to perform conversion outbound but not inbound.

Comment: I'm not about conversion. The question is it is possible to get that` Object mObject` not consumed by `onMessage`, bc at the moment I get null, I expect bc I'm trying to assign to object already consumed by `onMessage`.

Comment: If you override `onMessage()`, you have to call `super.onMessage()` so that the message is sent back to the calling thread. If your server takes longer than 5 seconds to reply, you will need to increase the `replyTimeout` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary